# Rendering Html Variables in Scala Play controller/template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Scala Play web app that is pulling html variables from the database, then placing them inside of a template. Something like this

```
<div>@myvar</div>
```

Where my var is an html string. The `myvar` is not being recongized by the template engine as html. So I get an output something like this

`<h3>MY HEADING</h3>`

instead of the h3 tags being rendered by the Scala play template engine to a proper html H3 tag.

Where do I need to render these variables? I have tried to do it in my controller but have obviously failed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap it in an `Html` object, otherwise the html is escaped.

```
<div>@Html(myvar)</div>
```